# Story about kids with weird mental powers in this big house

Tags: story-identification

Of these kids, one was a foster, went to a big house to be tested with multiple challenges with their brain from this guy and it gets crazy. The cover of the book is yellow and has a huge wooden house with kids around it. There are like 4 books in the series.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question so it's easier to make sense of?  Using something similar to standard English would be a good start...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Young adult book about experiment on teens in a big room with shifting platforms](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/159474/young-adult-book-about-experiment-on-teens-in-a-big-room-with-shifting-platforms)

Comment: Please provide all the information you remember. [Here is a guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) to help you. You can [edit] your question to include all the necessary information, but please do so in a clear and legible manner, respecting the rules of English.

Comment: @ZeissIkon - we don't close Story IDs before they have an accepted answer. Also, I'm almost absolutely certain that it's not what this question is asking for.

Comment: @Teo - if I managed to answer your question correctly, please make sure to come click the gray checkmark below the voting arrows on the left of my answer so that this question is marked as solved!

Answer (score 5):

***The Mysterious Benedict Society* by Trenton Lee Stewart**

[image]

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mysterious_Benedict_Society):

> After seeing an ad in the newspaper that reads, "ARE YOU A GIFTED CHILD LOOKING FOR SPECIAL OPPORTUNITIES?" Reynie Muldoon decides to take a test that is being hosted nearby. At the facility, he takes two rounds of testing, and is the only one in the room each time to pass - which he does easily by reading between the lines and figuring out the puzzles involved after refusing an offer to cheat. Invited to go to another facility to continue testing, he meets George, or "Sticky" Washington, a timid boy with an extraordinary gift for memory which he used to pass the tests. During the final two physical tests, he meets Kate Wetherall, an athletic and resourceful girl with a large bucket of objects, and Constance Contraire, a diminutive girl with a very defiant personality and a gift for wit, especially considering her minuscule size. All four children are also revealed to either have no parents or (in the case of Sticky, a runaway) to have been estranged from them.

In like the third book (there are three books in the series and 2 companion books), Constance is revealed to have some strange mental powers.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this counts as SFF, though.